# Sending SMS with Amazon AWS services PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk

I'm having trouble digging through the documentation for Amazon's AWS PHP-sdk.

Basically, I just need to send a standard text message to a number. I know it is possible because amazon allows you to send messages through the console directly via this screen:

[image: Amazon Console SMS]

It says something about using the "publish" method, but looking through that documentation really didn't provide any answers. [#Publish documentation link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html#_publish)

Any help or guidance is appreciated. I am currently looking for a solution that uses **V2** of the sdk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you see that screen please?

Comment: If you login to the AWS services, click on Amazon SNS, then send text message from console.

Answer (score 38):

No where have a doc showing it to use with PHP. Reading the Java and C# sdk I wrote the PHP version that works.

#### Updated on dec 20 '18

The args passed to `publish` method now have a new format. Fixed!

## How to send a SMS over AWS using PHP

First install **aws/aws-sdk-php**. Using composer:

`composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`

Create a php file with:

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'YOUR_KEY_HERE',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_HERE',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest'
);
$sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

$args = array(
    "MessageAttributes" => [
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'YOUR_SENDER_ID'
                ],
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'Transactional'
                ]
            ],
    "Message" => "Hello World! Visit www.tiagogouvea.com.br!",
    "PhoneNumber" => "FULL_PHONE_NUMBER"
);


$result = $sns->publish($args);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

The result must have one array with many data, including MessageId.

Comment: Although I appreciate your time and effort, I don't currently have an amazon account to test this with. Since the initial posting (time constraints, etc) we went with a different SMS provider. Again, I should have deleted this, but it may help someone in the future. Thank you!

Comment: @LesterPeabody I don't know. :(

Comment: there is a typo in SMSType value which should be "Transactional"

Comment: Fixed! Thansk @AhedEid!

Comment: Thanks @TiagoGouvêa that worked for me. If anyone needs a more detailed (complicated) version there's a script attached to this answer on the AWS forums that also worked for me: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234658#739232

Comment: Can u explain or mention steps to get credential key and secrete

Comment: This is no Longer working but sahilbathla answer worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895363/5078763

Comment: I agree to @SujayUN, I had a base source-code which was framed according to this answer, then suddenly it is no longer working. I retried the very same code (but with different values) and it is really no longer working. Maybe it is because it deviates with the current existing official docs -- of which **sahilbathla**'s answer addressed it.

Comment: Thanks for reply @AbelCallejo. Fixed the sample now.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using AWS SDK version prior to 3.0,  you still have create a topic and subscribe with an SMS type. But from 3.0 onward, you could send SMS direct to a number.

```
    $client = SnsClient::factory(array(
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'key',
        'secret' => 'secret')
    ));

    $message = 'Your verification code is 4';
     $payload = [
    'TopicArn' => 'arn:aws:sns:XXXXX',
        'Message'          => $message,
        'MessageStructure' => 'string',
        'MessageAttribute' => [
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
                'DataType'    => 'String',
                'StringValue' => 'Sender',
            ],
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
                'DataType'    => 'String',
                'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $result = $client->subscribe(array(
        'TopicArn' => 'arn:aws:sns:XXXXX',
        'Protocol' => 'sms',
        'Endpoint' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    ));
 $subarn = $result['SubscriptionArn'];
 $result = $client->publish($payload);
 $result = $client->unsubscribe(array(
    'SubscriptionArn' => $subarn,
 ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Somehow Tiago's answer didn't work for me. So I had a look at the publish API from AWS-SDK. Seems like there are no parameters of `SMSType` & `SenderID` in publish method. Check here -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#publish

So if you want to override these parameters, the following variation of Tiago's code should work fine -

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'YOUR_KEY_HERE',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_HERE',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest'
);
$sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

$args = array(
    "MessageAttributes" => [
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'YOUR_SENDER_ID'
                ],
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'Transactional'
                ]
            ],
    "Message" => "Hello World! Visit www.tiagogouvea.com.br!",
    "PhoneNumber" => "FULL_PHONE_NUMBER"
);

$result = $sns->publish($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help for people who still using PHP AWS SDK v2

Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51208701/551559

You would need to add new parameter in the source code.

```
// update file: aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Sdk/Resources/sns-2010-03-31.php

'Publish' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'PhoneNumber' => array( // new parameter
            'type' => 'string',
            'location' => 'aws.query',
        ),
    ),
),

// You just need to publish it and include the `PhoneNumber` parameter
$snsClientResult = $snsClient->publish([
    'Message' => 'YOUR_MESSAGE',
    'PhoneNumber' => 'PHONE_NUMBER',
    'MessageStructure' => 'SMS',
    'MessageAttributes' => [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'SENDER_ID',
        ],
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Promotional', // Transactional
        ]
    ]
]);

// Get the response
$snsClientResult['MessageId']
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution in php (add to params : 'http'=> [ 'verify' => false] )

```
<?php require './vendor/autoload.php';

$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'xxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxx',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest',
    'http'    => [
        'verify' => false
    ] ); $sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

$args = array(
    "MessageAttributes" => [
                // You can put your senderId here. but first you have to verify the senderid by customer support of AWS then you can use your senderId.
                // If you don't have senderId then you can comment senderId 
                // 'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
                //     'DataType' => 'String',
                //     'StringValue' => ''
                // ],
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'Transactional'
                ]
            ],
    "Message" => "TESTING SMS ORDUZ",
    "PhoneNumber" => "+573148832216"   // Provide phone number with country code );


$result = $sns->publish($args);

var_dump($result); // You can check the response
```

Answer (score -3):

To use the Publish action for sending a message to a mobile endpoint, such as an app on a Kindle device or mobile phone, you must specify the EndpointArn.

```
$result = $client->publish(array(
    'TopicArn' => 'string',
    'TargetArn' => 'string',
    // Message is required
    'Message' => 'string',
    'Subject' => 'string',
    'MessageStructure' => 'string',
    'MessageAttributes' => array(
        // Associative array of custom 'String' key names
        'String' => array(
            // DataType is required
            'DataType' => 'string',
            'StringValue' => 'string',
            'BinaryValue' => 'string',
        ),
        // ... repeated
    ),
));
```

Comment: EndpointArn is value of the TargetArn. If this value is empty, then you need to specify a value for phone number or TopicArn

Comment: Please update your example to reflect sending an SMS message to a specific mobile phone via phone number.