# Use Amazon SNS to send SMS messages using PHP AWS SDK v2?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I inherited a PHP project and it's heavily integrated with AWS SDK v2. Using v3 is not an option at this time.

My question is how can I leverage SNS to send text messages to specific numbers as needed? That is, I don't want to send mass notifications to a bunch of phone numbers subscribed to a specific topic when an action occurs, I want to send a notification to a specific phone number when an action occurs.

I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41268045/664881 but it appears to be using v3 of the AWS SDK. Is there an equivalent with v2 of the AWS SDK?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Publish` operation has no `PhoneNumber` parameter in v2.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work in PHP AWS SDK v2, but you need to add new parameter in the source code.

```
// update file: aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Sdk/Resources/sns-2010-03-31.php

'Publish' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'PhoneNumber' => array( // new parameter
            'type' => 'string',
            'location' => 'aws.query',
        ),
    ),
),

// You just need to publish it and include the `PhoneNumber` parameter
$snsClientResult = $snsClient->publish([
    'Message' => 'YOUR_MESSAGE',
    'PhoneNumber' => 'PHONE_NUMBER',
    'MessageStructure' => 'SMS',
    'MessageAttributes' => [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'SENDER_ID',
        ],
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Promotional', // Transactional
        ]
    ]
]);

// Get the response
$snsClientResult['MessageId']
```

Comment: You saved my life. Thanks! im with a zend project that can only use v2