# Send SMS with Amazon SNS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sms

I am trying to send SMS through the AWS SNS using the SDK for php.

I already configure the user in IAM (created a user to do this), grant full access to SNS service and check the keys many many times.

I am using the code that was posted in this topic for testing [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752336/sending-sms-with-amazon-aws-services-php) and receiving this message error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException' with message 'Error executing "Publish" on "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:   Sender SignatureDo (truncated...) SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? I am not able to find the solution

Comment: If you use @TiagoGouvêa example code, you must make sure the Access Key regional is in sync with the SNS service region you grant.

Comment: @mootmoot Tks! I just solved the problem. I dont understood whats happened but I created new group of user, new user and new key.