# 'SenderID' issues sending SMS on Amazon SNS (Official PHP SDK)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

For some reason the SenderID seems to revert to NOTICE - see here [image: Amazon SNS - SMS Notice] when I set the SenderID in the code.

When I leave the SenderID variable out, it sends as the default set - this is good, but we will be occasionally changing the name for different uses.

I am using the Official PHP SDK, with the code below:

```
$aws_cred = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'GOT THE KEY',
        'secret' => 'GOT THE SECRET',
    ),
    'region' => 'eu-west-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest'
    );
    $sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($aws_cred);

    $args = array(
    "SenderID" => "MySendID",
    "SMSType" => "Promotional",
    "Message" => "Amazon y u do dis??",
    "PhoneNumber" => "+number"
    );

    $result = $sns->publish($args);
```

I am sending to the UK (so SID works there), and also it is within the 11 character limit.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Cheers

Comment: I just wanted to comment to say, bravo on the `GOT THE KEY` and `GOT THE SECRET`. I’m not going to be able to get that song out of my head, now! XD

Comment: @MartinBean One of the greats!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SenderID using Amazon Web Services PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605977/senderid-using-amazon-web-services-php-sdk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The search system didn't materialise this originally, but finally, I have found it.

QUOTE FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43748448/7586984

> I found the solution. Set the args this way. It works!
>
> ```
> $args = array(
>     'MessageAttributes' => [
>           'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
>                'DataType' => 'String',
>                'StringValue' => 'YourSenderName'
>         ]
>      ],
>       "SMSType" => "Transactional",
>       "PhoneNumber" => "+87654321",
>       "Message" => "Hello World!"
> );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> (Optional) For Sender ID, type a custom ID that contains up to 11
>   alphanumeric characters, including at least one letter and no spaces.
>   The sender ID is displayed as the message sender on the receiving
>   device. For example, you can use your business brand to make the
>   message source easier to recognize.
>
> Support for sender IDs varies by country. For example, messages
>   delivered to U.S. phone numbers will not display the sender ID. For
>   the countries that support sender IDs, see Supported Regions and
>   Countries.
>
> If you do not specify a sender ID, the message will display a long
>   code as the sender ID in supported countries. For countries that
>   require an alphabetic sender ID, the message displays NOTICE as the
>   sender ID.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html

to sumerise you cant use spaces(you have one) and it wont always work, it depends on country and carrier, it wont work in more places than it will

Comment: Should've been more clear sorry. I am sending to a UK number (+44) which allows SenderID, and the SenderID I'm actually using has no spaces. Seems to work when I leave it out so I'm at a loss as to why it's not working, have even tried using the full variable name `AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID`.

Comment: its really not a country issue but a carrier one, you really shouldent expect this to work

Comment: I wouldn't, and would be less confused if it wasn't for the fact that when I don't specify the SenderID in the code, the default SenderID that i've set in AWS does send successfully.

Comment: SNS has no UK region, so they are probably still be carried from outside

Comment: Yes, but the SenderID works either way when it is being defaulted, just not set manually within the arguments array