# The SenderID and SMSType is taking default one in AWS SNS sdk for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SDK for PHP. 
I am trying to send messages to numbers. Which is working for few numbers and will not work if DND is activated for South-east.

I tried both the Transactional and Promotional but which is not working for DND activated numbers. The senderID and smsType didn't change.
Which is taking the default one even though I mentioned the smsType and senderID.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752336/sending-sms-with-amazon-aws-services-php?answertab=votes#tab-top) which I used to implement. I googled for samples. I didn't get any proper documentation for SNS using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my question. I am posting this code believing that it would help some one in need.

I was doing wrong in while passing the senderID and SMSType.

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

$client = new SnsClient(['region' => 'ap-southeast-1', 'version' => 'latest', 
'credentials' => ['key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']]);

$result = $client->publish(array('Message' => $message_mobile, 'PhoneNumber' => $mobile_no, 
'MessageAttributes' => array('AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => array('StringValue' => 'Transactional', 'DataType' => 'String'),
'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => array('StringValue' => 'LIMAHB', 'DataType' => 'String'))));
```