# Does the AWS SNS SMS' sender name change for those countries with no support to Sender IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

In our AWS SNS implementation, we sent out **[Transactional](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk)** SMS messages [by using the PHP AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752336/sending-sms-with-amazon-aws-services-php#41268045).

At first, when we sent out the messages, the name of the sender was still `NOTICE` then suddenly the name of the sender changed into `INFOSMS`, `INFO`, `NXSMSPH`, `+14152129583`.

[image][image]

Is this a normal behavior for those implementers under the countries with [no support to Sender IDs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html)? Does the sender name change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you (or AWS) is sending SMS to foreign country, there are different ways how transport will go, depending on a contracts. There may be peer-to-peer connection, which mean two operators have agreement to send SMS directly. However, since they must manage this for every operator in a world they do business, they usually use gateways (so called SMS-Hubs). Most of them are just proxies, which means they pass sms to destination, but some of them may change some values (such as sender id, etc..) 
Also the message can pass each time thru different such gateways. 
So if the destination country is not allowing alphanumeric sender id, such message can have only two options:

```
- to be rejected 
- to be sent, but with the sender id they have had set through the contract
```

Comment: can you state some references that would support the answer

Comment: Uh, this is from my head as I work in this field and many vendors even dont put documents online.
Perhaps here is a good starting point:

    https://www.gsma.com/newsroom/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/IR7520.pdf